# list being printed out weirdly python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

`[796, 829, 1159, 1162]`

I also have a list like this:

`['144 154', '145 151', '145 152', '145 153', '145 154', '146 152', '146 153', '146 154', '147 153', '147 154']`
These are not to scale

What I want to do is use the first lists elements as index for the last array

I have tried this piece of code:

```
contacts = []
for i in findres:
    contacts += rulelines[i]
print contacts
```

where `findres` is the first list and `rulelines` is the last list
However this prints the `contacts` list out weirdly:

`['5', ' ', '7', '2', '5', ' ', '1', '0', '5', '7', ' ', '1', '5', '0', '7', ' ', '1', '5', '3']`

I'm sure its easy but where am I going wrong??

The desirable output I believe is `['5 72','5 105', '7 150',7 153']`

I have not put down all of the list elements as there are over 100 elements in each

Comment: Can you tell me what your desirable output is?

Comment: Well, if the first list is `findres` and the second list is `rulelines`, then that won't produce the output you've given.

Comment: Can you include `rulelines` and `findres` in your code as well ?

Comment: Are you sure findres indexes are inside rulelines boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a template:

```
findres = [5, 7, 15, 22]
contacts = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') # dummy list

result = [ contacts[index] for index in findres ]
print result

# ['f', 'h', 'p', 'w']
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like when you assign `contacts = rulelines[i]` you're actually assigning the `rulelines[i]` string. You should do `contacts.append(rulelines[i])` to add the the contact to the list, otherwise you're constantly overwriting over the last assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to extract the first number in every elements of `findres` first. Then, use those extracted numbers as an index for another array

```
>>> findres = ['144 154', '145 151', '145 152', '145 153', '145 154', '146 152', '146 153', '146 154', '147 153', '147 154']
>>> first_elements = [c.split()[0] for c in findres]
>>> print first_elements 

['144', '145', '145', '145', '145', '146', '146', '146', '147', '147']

>>> contact = []
>>> for i in first_elements:
        contacts.append(rulelines[i])
```